# How can I localize a date pipe using ngx translate

Tags: angular

I wanna translate this date pipe to Norwegian language. Is there a specific way to translate date pipes that is different to normal text or variable translation.

{{activity.feed.timestamp | timeAgo}}

Answer (score 0):

You can check [ngx-timeago](https://www.npmjs.com/package/) that has i18n support.

> I18n By default, there is no intl service available, as the default
>   formatter doesn't provide language support. You should provide one, if
>   you end up with a formatter that needs it (either
>   TimeagoCustomFormatter which is provided by the lib or your own). The
>   purpose of the intl service is to contain all the necessary i18n
>   strings used by your formatter.
>
> ```
> import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
> import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
> import { Timeago, TimeagoIntl, TimeagoFormatter, TimeagoCustomFormatter } from 'ngx-timeago';
> import { AppComponent } from './app';
>
> export class MyIntl extends TimeagoIntl {
> // do extra stuff here...
> }
>
> @NgModule({
>   imports: [
>     BrowserModule,
>     TimeagoModule.forRoot({
>       intl: { provide: TimeagoIntl, useClass: MyIntl },
>       formatter: { provide: TimeagoFormatter, useClass: TimeagoCustomFormatter },
>     })
>   ],
>   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
> })
> export class AppModule { }
> ```
>
> There is support for a large number of languages out of the box. This
>   support is based on the string objects taken from jquery-timeago.
>
> To use any of the languages provided, you will have to import the
>   language strings and feed them to the intl service.
>
> ```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
> import { TimeagoIntl } from 'ngx-timeago';
> import {strings as englishStrings} from 'ngx-timeago/language-strings/en';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'app',
>   template: `
>     <div timeago [date]="1553683912689"></div>
>   `
> })
> export class AppComponent {
>   constructor(intl: TimeagoIntl) {
>     intl.strings = englishStrings;
>     intl.changes.next();
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> You can also customize the language strings or provide your own.